# How to change material-header-row color and align material-header-title to the center of App Layout?

Tags: css, dart, angular-dart, dart-html

I want to change only the color of `material-header-row` with `::ng-deep` but it doesn't works, and also want to align `material-header-title` to the center of the header row.

app_component.html

```
<material-content>
    <header class="material-header shadow">
        <div class="material-header-row">
            <material-button icon
                             class="material-drawer-button" (trigger)="drawer.toggle()">
                <material-icon icon="menu"></material-icon>
            </material-button>
            <span class="material-header-title">Simple Layout</span>
            <div class="material-spacer"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
</material-content>
```

app_component.css

```
:host {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover {
  color: $mat-black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

::ng-deep header.material-header.material-header-row {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
::ng-deep header.material-header.material-header-row {
```

would only match

```
<header class="material-header material-header-row">
```

Instead

```
:host ::ng-deep header.material-header .material-header-row {
```

should do what you want (added space)

Comment: yes it worked but not as expected, have a look at the images added in the question

Comment: Try adding `:host ` at the beginning of the selector. Perhaps the selectivity is to low against the default color

Comment: If you change background-color of `<div class="material-header-row">` in the Chrome devtools, do you get the desired effect?

Comment: No, the color of `material-header-row` changes but the background color of `material-header` remains the same

Comment: have a look at the images added in the question`::ng-deep header.material-header.material-header {
  background-color: $mat-white;
  color: $mat-black;
}

:host ::ng-deep header.material-header .material-header-row {
  background-color: $mat-red;
  color: $mat-white;
}`

Comment: Sounds like you need 2 rules. Once with `.material-header-row` as in my answer, and the same again, but without `.material-header-row`

Comment: I want to include `material-tabs` in `material-header` and want to keep header with dark color, but while applying dark background color the tabs also reflects the same color.

Comment: So I was thinking to make the first header-row with the dark background and second row of tabs with the light background

Comment: I see. Perhaps you need to wrap the tabs in another element (`<div>` or whatever), where you set the background-color that you want to have in the tabs. Color is usually inherited.

Comment: While wrapping up in a `<div>` the default material styles doesn't works.